# Get the value of a cell that's the address of the active cell without using macros or VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula

The following formula returns a text representation of the cell address:

```
=address(row(),Column())
```

I'd like to have the value of the active cell (as formula in a cell) without using VBA or macros and should be updated while moving around.

Is this possible?

Comment: You would need an Event macro.

Comment: Didn't get your question. Can you explain with the help of an Example ?

Comment: Can you provide some example of the output?

Comment: Not possible with formula. A formula cannot reference the active cell, it references a fixed range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't update *completely* automatically - you will need to press <kbd>F9</kbd> to make it refresh - but it will provide the value of the active cell:

```vb
=CELL("contents")
```

Other options (address, row number, column number, is the cell locked, et cetera) are also available - see [the Microsoft Documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/cell-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf) for more information.  When the optional second argument of `CELL` is omitted, it defaults to the Active Cell.

The **only** way to make this update when you change cell would be to use VBA.  You can force the recalculation whenever the Selection changes, instead of having to press F9 like so:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Me.Calculate
End Sub
```

(Since this will prevent you from copying or pasting data, you might want to only run the recalculation while you don't have something cut/copied, like so:  `If Application.CutCopyMode<1 Then Me.Calculate` instead)

Comment: Its sad this won't update completely automatically. that's exactly what i wanted. Thanks for your reply